# Not clear about the use of .repeat() in the following code

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

In a python code that was given to me from my former colleague, there is a line that I am not able to understand. It is,

```
single_channel_depth_ch = single_channel_depth.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,19,1,1)
```

where,
single_channel_depth is an array with dimension (1408, 376, 1).
I understood that the unsqueeze() will drop the dimension with value 1 and make an array of (1408, 376). But, I do not understand the meaning of .repeat(1,19,1,1).

As I have checked, I found that, the repeat() will replace the array elements with the elements passed as an arguments to it.

Is my understanding correct? or is there some other meaning of the code line mentioned above?

Comment: This does not seem like numpy to me, maybe torch.Tensors?

Comment: I suspect the original author changes the array/Tensor shape to (1408, 1, 376, 1), and then repeats it n times along each dimension according to the four values passed to repeat. That means simply means that the input array/Tensor of shape 1408, 376, 1 is repeated 19 times along a new 2nd dimension.

Comment: Note that that is essentially equivalent to broadcasting it along a new 2nd dimension

Comment: yes, single_channel_depth is a pytorch tensor.

Comment: That makes sense, I hope the other comments help explain what's going on

Answer (score 2):

The `unsqueeze` method *adds* a *singleton* (size 1) dimension to the array.

The first argument is the tensor, and the second is the index at which to insert the singleton dimension

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])
torch.unsqueeze(x, 0)
```

> tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4]])

```
torch.unsqueeze(x, 1)
```

> ```
> tensor([[ 1],
>         [ 2],
>         [ 3],
>         [ 4]])
> ```

---

Regarding the `repeat` method, you are correct in your understanding. It replicates the elements of the array along the given dimensions.

The argument you pass into that method is the number of times to repeat this tensor along *each* dimension.

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
x.repeat(4, 2)
```

> ```
> tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3],
>         [ 1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3],
>         [ 1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3],
>         [ 1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3]])
> ```

```
x.repeat(4, 2, 1).size()
```

> torch.Size([4, 2, 3])

---

In the code you provided, the repeat method is replicating the array along the second dimension 19 times and the third and fourth dimensions once.

This will result in a new array with shape (1408, 19, 376, 1), which is created by replicating the original array along the second dimension 19 times. The third and fourth dimensions are left unchanged.